90s-00s movie. Haunted house, father possessed
I saw a film around 9-10 years ago on DVD, here is what I remember:

It was about a little boy, similar looking to the boy from the sixth
sense
I think they moved into a new house - the mother, father, and the
boy
The father becomes psychotic  
I think there was one scene where the father walks into the
bathroom and some old wrinkly naked woman starts walking
towards him
There was an old black guy in the movie that had a red Cadillac and
he had nose bleeds every time the little boy was in danger

That's all i can remember.

Most probably you're after The Shining miniseries:

Now, nursing a life of sobriety and pulling in work as a writer, Jack
  and his family take on the job of looking after the Overlook Hotel, a
  large colonial building in a picturesque valley in the Colorado
  Rockies.
It gradually becomes apparent that the hotel's ghosts are more than
  figurative and far from peaceful.
Jack's character becomes progressively darker, first by scolding Danny
  for violating his rules that he was to stay out of the guest rooms,
  then eventually returning to his drunken self (the ghosts supplying an
  open bar for Jack prior to their ball).

And here's the trailer set to a scene with Dick Hallorann (the old black guy).
It can also be Kubrick's The Shining, but the details from your description fit the miniseries better.
